# C++ - wrapping method calls to catch exceptions

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I have a third-party client library which has a bunch of methods that sends messages via a socket. If the socket becomes invalid (e.g. connection lost with remote server), then the methods throw an exception. I want to wrap these methods cleanly so that I can catch, log and do reconnection etc. in a central place. I basically want to avoid this boiler plate everytime I call any method on the client object:

```
try {
    auto result = client->doSomething(someValue);
} catch(TransportException e) {
    cerr << "Connection failed..." << endl;
    client->getTransport()->reconnect(); // some reconnection logic
}
```

There are quite a few methods, so extending the class or creating a manual wrapper around it is ruled out.

I have considered Macros, but I rather than not use it if possible.

I came across [this post](http://cppguru.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/c-proxy-template/) that implements proxying in C++ (like in Java), but I'm not sure how to catch the exceptions thrown by the client methods.

Is there any way to achieve this cleanly? (I'm using C++ 11).

Comment: Pass an `std::function` to a method that wraps the call in a try/catch

Comment: I also considered that, but the catch block won't have access to the `client` object. Unless I passed the client object also as a parameter.

Comment: relevant: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/01/16/exception-boundaries.aspx